# Can't watch YouTube

Tags: sound, flash, youtube

I am running lubuntu on a Dell mini12. it was working fine until a couple of weeks ago. Now you tube videos have problems playing back sound. I've tried installing the latest flash. My browser is Firefox but it happens on Chromium too.

Comment: If you are happy to install it, Google Chrome should work because it has Pepper Flash built in. In fact, I'm using it on Lubuntu right now.

Comment: thanks i'll try that as a good stopgap, but would be keen to get to the root of the flash problem.

Comment: I doubt you will ever get it working. Flash has not be supported on Linux for over 1.5 years.

Comment: Tim, I tried installing chrome but the same glitch appears. Then I uninstalled Chrome, tried to purge flash and to load Pepperflash for firefox. But the glitch is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be related to the change youtube recently made to HTML5 videos by default. Early February if I remember correctly.

Related Article: [Youtube Says Goodbye to Flash](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Youtube-Says-Goodbye-to-Flash-HTML5-Is-Now-Default-471426.shtml)

Note: Would have posted as a comment not an answer but don't yet have the rep for it

Comment: No, what you did was right! This is a full answer :) And, in fact, this answer just got you the rep!